# "Where" extention returning duplicate records on a List but not IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having an issue with a Where statement; I have an object and a method to fetch its records

```
public class VehiclePart
{ 
   public int VehicleId { get; set; }
   public string PartNumber { get; set; }
   // and other properties
}


public List<VehiclePart> GetByVehiclePartsByVehicleId(int vehicleId, string partNumber)
{
    var vehicleParts = GetAll(); //returns IQueryable from EF repo
    var thisVehiclesParts = vehicleParts.Where(g => g.VehicleId == vehicleId).ToList();
    var parts = thisVehiclesParts.Where(g => g.PartId == partNumber).ToList();

    return parts;
}
```

The above statement works fine; but we wanted to change this to use a caching mechanism for the entire table. After implementing it we removed the caching piece and just called .ToList() on the GetAll() method. This should bring back the entire table into a List collection in memory. This works and we receive the same number of records in the List as exists in the table. See Below with the changes

```
public List<VehiclePart> GetByVehiclePartsByVehicleId(int vehicleId, string partNumber)
{
    var vehicleParts = GetAll().ToList(); //resolve query here to a list in memory
    var thisVehiclesParts = vehicleParts.Where(g => g.VehicleId == vehicleId).ToList();
    var parts = thisVehiclesParts.Where(g => g.PartId == partNumber).ToList();

    return parts;
}
```

The issue arises is now that we have applied the .Where(g => g.VehicleId == vehicleId).ToList(); to a list object in the .Net Memory heap we get duplicate results where as when we did not resolve the query after the GetAll() method and let the .Where() method would be applied to an IQueryable we do not duplicate results.

The below fixes the issue

```
.Where(g => g.VehicleId == vehicleId).Distinct().ToList();
```

I only receive unique records with the Distinct() method now; but why do I receive duplicate records when the .Where method is applied to a List instead of an IQueryable? Where should filter the list and only return the items once instead I see duplication anywhere between 10-20 times.

For anyone wanting to see the GetAll Code

```
public class EntityService<T> : IEntityService<T> where T: BaseEntity.Entity
{
    protected IContext _context;
    protected DbSet<T> _dbset;
    protected NagsService(IContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbset = _context.Set<T>();
    }
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be good to see the caching mechanism, if possible.

Comment: Caching mechanism is not in use in the code example so you shouldn't need it. GetAll() would be replaced with GetAllCached() which returns List<VehiclePart> which is the same as GetAll().ToList(); GetAll() returns IQueryable<VehiclePart>. I removed that call during troubleshooting to eliminate that as a possibility.

Comment: Maybe an important question is what *should* the dataset look like - for example if you ran the query on the database in SQL

Comment: @DaveBish Thanks for the response, if we execute the query in SQL it looks exactly as it should and the first code block does that correctly. When the Where is applied to an IQueryable and ran on the SQL server it works; when the Where is applied to a List in the Heap it returns duplicates.

Comment: The collection of VehicleParts have several records with the same VehicleID? By the name it looks like a One to Many (Vehicle -> VehicleParts). What happend when you add the PartNumer in the same where as an `&&` statement?

Comment: @DJ you are correct it is a One to Many (Vehicle -> VehicleParts); combining the query does not alter the behavior; they were split into separate Where().ToList() statements so that we could trouble shoot where the issue popped up.

Comment: If you are not going to use the collection of `thisVehicleParts` for any other operation, i suggest you to remove the `ToList()` from that line, and let the next where conditions handle what data you want to retreive.

You are not selecting any specifc field. So it just returns the entities that matches the condition as there are!

Comment: You seem to be saying your list contains item `x` with `VehicleId` `y` once and that `list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == y)` returns `x` more than once?  The way `Enumerable.Where` is implemented, this isn't possible.

Comment: Is there any `VehiclePartId`?

Comment: @DJ yes I understand I should remove that collection; like I said the steps were broken out into smaller ones so we could find the issue. It was originally  return GetAllCached().Where(g => g.VehicleId == vehicleId && g.PartId == partNumber).ToList(); but it was broken down into smaller steps for troubleshooting and to make this post easier to follow.

Comment: @CharlesMager Yes you are 100% correct that's how it should work, but that is not how it is working.in your example 'x' is returned multiple times when ran where is applied to the List<VehicleParts> but not when its applied to IQueryable<VehicleParts>; additionally we have confirmed that List<VehicleParts> in my example has the same number of records as the database table, there is not duplication in List<VehicleParts> before the Where method is applied to it.

Comment: And `x` definitely only exists in your list *once*?  You can [look at the implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e73922753675387a,references) - this isn't possible.  It simply iterates all items in the source and decides whether or not to return each item.  Can you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows this behaviour?

Comment: @CharlesMager The table VehicleParts in the database has 940415 records the List<VehicleParts> also contains 940415 when it is called as GetAll().ToList(). If the where is applied directly as a query in the database or to an IQueryable(first service method example) I receive 17 records. If the Where is applied to the List<VehicleParts> in memory I receive 170, the same 17 records repeated 10 times (this is the second service method example).   Also thanks for the Implementation link that was my next step.

Comment: So, humour me - what is the count of `GetAll().ToList().Distinct()`?

Comment: @CharlesMager Thank you again for your help; GetAll().ToList().Distinct().Count() is not 940,415.... It is less (~75k) though we know that the correct number of parts would be roughly 940k. There is an odd architecture in place where the entity is actually calling a SQL View that queries multiple tables and combines them, which I think could cause something like them not being considered as unique.

Comment: It all backs to what data are you pulling into the object VehiclePart.  What is a duplicate and what not? are there any unique identifier?

Comment: So, it seems that your 'table/view' contains duplicates and whatever SQL EF translates your `Where` clause to results in the duplicates being removed (this is the `IQueryable<T>` case). Thankfully, it does appear .NET is working correctly ;)

Comment: @CharlesMager but if you you a Select Distinct on the view on the SQL server then we get 940,415. So it doesn't seem to consider them distinct in .NET but in SQL it is.

Comment: @CharlesMager SELECT distinct *  FROM [dbo].[VehiclePart] ran on the sql server returns 940,415 while calling GetAll().ToList().Distinct().Count() returns ~73k.  To Answer DJ The view cannot have a Key on the sql server but the entity that matches the view has 4 fields that are set as Keys [Key]
        [Required]
        public string PartId 
        [Key]
        public string PartDetailId 
        [Key]
        public string ManufacturerPartId 
        [Key]
        public string Manufacturer

Comment: Do you override `Equals` in `VehiclePart` (you probably shouldn't)?  Assuming you don't, then EF believes a lot of them are duplicates as it's returning the same object multiple times. I think with ~1m rows you're going to find this tricky to debug.  Without a verifiable example we're not doing much better than guessing.

Comment: @Charles Mager we do not override the 'Equals' method anywhere so that shouldn't cause an issue.

Comment: var countAppliedToList = GetAll().ToList().Distinct().Count(); ~73k 
var countAppliedToIQueryable = GetAll().Distinct().Count(); 940415
running select distinct * in the database also returns 940,415